# gnome-terminal exits with status 127 on ubuntu 18.04 but how do I find the stacktrace?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnome

`gnome-terminal` suddenly stopped working and when I run it via another terminal emulator (`termite`) it throws an error:

```
> sudo gnome-terminal     
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.Terminal exited with status 127
```

Where can I find the actual stacktrace?